# Create categorical column based on string values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have kind of a simple problem, but I'm having trouble achieving what I want. I have a district column, with 32 different values for all districts in a city. I want to create a column "sector" that says which sector that district belongs to.
I thought the obvious approach was through a dictionary and map, but couldn't make it work:

```
sectores={'sector oriente':['Vitacura, Las Condes, Lo Barnechea', 'La Reina','Ñuñoa','Providencia'],
     'sector suroriente':['Peñalolén','La Florida', 'Macul'],
     'sector sur': ['La Granja','La Pintana','Lo Espejo','San Ramón','La Cisterna','El Bosque','Pedro Aguirre Cerda','San Joaquín','San Miguel'],
     'sector surponiente':['Maipú','Estación Central','Cerrillos'],
     'sector norponiente':['Cerro Navia','Lo Prado','Pudahuel','Quinta Normal','Renca'],
     'sector norte':['Conchalí','Huechuraba','Independencia','Recoleta','Quilicura'],
     'sector centro':['Santiago']}
```

Noticed I needed to switch keys and values:

```
sectores = dict((y,x) for x,y in sectores.items())
```

Then tried to map it:

```
df['sectores']=df['district'].map(sectores)
```

But I'm getting:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is this the right approach? Should I try something else?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is what df['district'] looks like:

```
district

Maipú
Quilicura
Independencia
Conchalí
...
```

Comment: Please show us an extract of `df['district']`, looks like you might have `list` objects in your series, which is incompatible with dictionary keys.

Comment: There you go. There's no list in the series, but my dict is made out of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `lists` as the keys in your `dict`, which is not possible because lists are mutable and not hashable.

Instead, use the strings by iterating through the values:

```
sectores = {i: k for k, v in sectores.items() for i in v}
```

Then, you can use `pd.Series.map` and

```
df['sectores']=df['district'].map(sectores)
```

should work

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't know you could create dictionaries with lots of keys for a value without using lists .That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot